# Set TTL for Redis cache to specific time

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I am using RedisCacheManager using spring boot. I want to expire the cache at 23:59:59 everyday i.e end of the day. How can I do that? I can see that it can be done only relatively by using  `Duration.ofHours(3)` Or  `Duration.ofMinutes(3)` etc. But in my case, I want to set the ttl to a specific time, so that the cache expires every day at 23:59:59. Below is the code snippet I am using:

```
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        Duration expiration = Duration.ofHours(3);

        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager =
                RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                        .cacheDefaults(
                                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                                        .serializeValuesWith(
                                                RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                                                        new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()))
                                        .entryTtl(expiration))
                        .build();

        redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(false);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }
```

Comment: Calculate the number of seconds from now until the end of today and use Duration.ofSeconds